# Divide array into two arrays and set values to odd and even

Tags: javascript

I can't get a result I wanted:

```
Even Array is: 2, 18, 38, -10, 0, 104
Odd Array is: 3, 13, -5, 11
```

Two arrays where one contains even numbers another odd.

Here is the code:

```
let arrayMain = [2, 3, 13, 18, -5, 38, -10, 11, 0, 104];
let oddArray = [];
let evenArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arrayMain.length; i++){
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        evenArray.push(arrayMain[i]);
    }
    else {
        oddArray.push(arrayMain[i]);
    }
}

console.log("Odd Array is " + oddArray);
console.log("Even Array is " + evenArray);
```

It gives me:

```
Odd Array is 3,18,38,11,104
Even Array is 2,13,-5,-10,0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `i` is the *counter* `i % 2` will divide divide the array into odd and even places, not odd and even values. You need to do `arrayMain[i] % 2`

Comment: Please add a `debugger;` inside the code and verify each value and condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the value, not the index.

```
if (arrayMain[i] % 2 == 0) {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^ ^
```